# Behringer Xenyx Q502USB with Boya MIC Hissing Noise and Low Vocal Sound Issue

Tags: mixer, behringer

I am totally new to sound. I have been using USB MIC and Boya (with USB adaptor). I record my voice while screen recording. I should had gone with Audio Interface but I got this mixer without XLR MIC. I don't have XLR mic. I have Boya BY-M1 mic. I got two adapters (TRS connectors). I plugged in simple headphone audio and Boya mic pins in mixer and used phones. I could hear audio/sound from laptop but I could not listen to my voice from MIC. I turned 'Gain' and 'Level' in first column and turned phones knob. I can listen to my voice but really low but a ready loud hiss and background noise. I tried "To Phones" and "To main mix" together and separate but no success.
Also when I check "Listen to this device" from mic settings only them i hear my voice.
I wanted to record my voice and monitor it at same time.
I am using screen capturing software or sometimes audacity.
Did I make mistake by going with mixir?
Should I had gone with audio mixer like Focusrite?
[image: Mixer with Boya and adaptors]

[image: audacity - too much noise and hiss]

Am I doing it wrong? Is XLR microphone a must to get clean voice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an impedance mis-match.

Your mic is designed for consumer-level laptops, cameras, phones etc which all expect (cheap) high impedance microphones. [Boya](http://www.boya-mic.com/lavaliermicrophones/BY-M1.html) states the BY-M1 is '1000Ω or less', which is borderline mid-high impedance.
Presumably your previous USB adaptor was also designed for consumer-level headset mics.

Your new mixer is expecting a (professional) low impedance mic. Typically 100Ω or so.

There's a really good explanation of why this mismatch means a rough ride for your audio here - [Microphone Impedance: What Is It And Why Is It Important?](https://mynewmicrophone.com/microphone-impedance/)

You can use a DI (Direct Injector) Box to overcome this mismatch - however, even a half-decent DI box will cost more than your existing mic.
Practically, you would be better off getting a real low impedance mic.

Comment: Alright. Thanks. So if I get a 3.5 female to xlr male connector and use that to connect boya will it work? or I just saw there are xlr lavalier microphone (requires phantom power) available. But my mixer has 15v phantom power but xlr mics require 48v phantom power.

Comment: Just changing the connector will not change the impedance - you need something like this https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/68656-REG/Shure_A95U_A95U_Reversible_Impedance.html The [Behringer manual](https://images.static-thomann.de/pics/atg/atgdata/document/manual/281982_q1202usb_q1002usb_q802usb_q502usb_m_en.pdf) is horribly unclear as to what its phantom power output is, & there are many online discussions about it. Phantom is supposed to be 48v, the manual says 'switchable' +48v/+15v then never mentions how you'd switch it; which is… ermm… (swearing redacted).